# Throttle the call to downstream systems

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebusrelay

Requirement is to build a proxy ESB layer to throttle the calls to the downstream salesforce system to control the concurrent call threshold. Am not sure how to achieve this in Azure services, recall vaguely Logic App can throttle to max invoked instances not sure if this or anyother ones would fit better.. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure API Management service can be used for call throttling based on request parameters(Ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-flexible-throttling)

Logic app has concurrency control feature which allows you to control the number of logic app running instances at the same time or in parallel as shown below.
[image: Logic app settings concurrency feature]